# Wrong indent size in multi-line string definition in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, coding-style, webstorm

WebStorm 10 is messing up the tabbing indentation on multi-line string definitions:

[image: Example]

Anyone know what formatting setting is responsible for this?

---

Seems like it might have something to do with declaration v.s. definition styles, because looks like it works on declaration:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no setting to fix your issue. Your settings are likely correct. The incorrect formatting is caused by a bug in the current version of Webstorm (10.0.3). There is currently an open issue on the jetbrains bug tracker. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16696.